# sum on np.array vs python list: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum

I need to sum over an indicator function in a set.

`sum()` can be directly used on np.array with no issues.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.arange(10)
ans = sum(y % 2 == 0)
```

However, `sum()` cannot be used directly on python lists.

```
z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ans = sum(z % 2 == 0)
```

On the other hand, this works for np.array and python lists.

```
ans = sum(each % 2 == 0 for each in z)
print(ans)
```

The question is why? Both np.array and python lists should be iterables. What makes np.array support the additional syntax?

Comment: It's simply the fact that `numpy.array` defines the `__mod__` operator, while the python  `list` doesn't (https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Comment: You are confused. `sum` can be used *just fine* on `list` objects and `np.ndarray` objects, although, **you should never use the `sum` function on `nd.array` objects**. You should use the `np.sum` function or the `.sum` method on the array directly, so `(y % 2 == 0).sum()` instead. The *reason* your code isn't working with `list` objects is because `%` does not work on list objects, so `z % 2 == 0` fails. This has *nothing to do with lists being iterable*. List objects *don't support vectorized operations like numpy arrays*.

Comment: The error in the subject  line clearly points to the `%`, not the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Python list doesn't implement that out of the box, if you want, you can always subclass python list and have own custom list to allow modulo operation via `__mod__` method:

```py
class MyList(list):
    def __mod__(self, i):
        return [item%i for item in self]
    
>> data = MyList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>> data%3

[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

You can take a look at official Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to know about the methods that can be overwritten.

Comment: So, it is similar to C++'s overloading? I see that there are similar methods such as __ add.__, __ div.__, etc. In the same way, I can also define matrix operations, or some crazy stuff, if I want to?

Comment: Yes you can define, there are plethora of methods that can be overwritten, I have attached a link to the official documentation, you can take a look at there.

Comment: Python lists don't define math operators.  `+` and `*` are concatenate and repeat.  Lists can contain all kinds of things, so it doesn't make sense to define number only methods.  List comprehensions are the usual way of performuing elementwise operations on lists.